# How to make a enum field to be updatable in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to create a simple RoR application. I have faced a problem with enums for User categories.

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  before_save :name_to_sentence_case

  extend Enumerize
  enumerize :category, in: [:admin, :staff, :customer]

  VALID_NAME_REGEX = /\A[a-z]+\z/i
  VALID_PHONE_REGEX = /\A[0-9]+\z/

  validates :first_name, presence: true, length: {maximum: 20}, format: {with: VALID_NAME_REGEX}
  validates :last_name, presence: true, length: {maximum: 30}, format: {with: VALID_NAME_REGEX}
  validates :category, presence: true
  validates :password, presence: true, length: {minimum: 6}
  validates :phone, presence: true, length: {maximum: 15}, uniqueness: true, format: {with: VALID_PHONE_REGEX}

  has_secure_password

  def name_to_sentence_case
    self.first_name = first_name.humanize
    self.last_name = last_name.humanize
  end
end
```

I can create a user from rails console and set category based on specified categories and the system won't allow to create a user with another categories. However, I can not update the category of an existing user even if there is a correct category.

Comment: what are you sending for the update data exactly?  Is it a string or the number in that array?

Comment: @RockwellRice it is a string e.g. 'string' or "string". It works for creating a user but not for updating

Comment: I believe you need the number for this, at least that is what I always use when working with enums, the position in the array.  The field is an integer field in the database right?

Comment: @RockwellRice Nope. It is the category field is stored as a string. I have even tried to use an array of strings with categories and using it via  inclusion: { in: array}. Anyways, it works only for creation, not for updating

Answer (score 0):

Better method is to create a hash. So you just update a numeric value.
For Example

```
CATEGORY = {
  0 => 'admin',
  1 => 'staff',
  2 => 'customer'
}
```

You just store value numeric value in database(0,1 or 2) and you will know who it is from your hash.

Answer (score 0):

Rails has build in `enum` helper. According to [Documentation](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html) you can use it in next way:

in model:

```
enum category: [:admin, :staff, :customer]
```

your `category` field should be integer type or

```
enum category: { admin: :admin, staff: :staff, customer: :customer }
```

if you want to have string type field

than you can update your `user` in very simple way

```
@user.admin!
```

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate on [Oleg's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3884750/oleg-sobchuk) answer, you will be able to pass in the enumerable option as string the parameter i.e.

```
@user.update(phone: "123-234-1234", category: 'admin')
```

or category

```
@user.update(phone: "123-234-1234", category: :admin)
```

See lines 21, 22 at [source code on github](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/a9dc45459abcd9437085f4dd0aa3c9d0e64e062f/activerecord/lib/active_record/enum.rb#L148)